# Unable to select api level lower than 20 for Graphical Layout for layout XML files

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have started some android recently, things going well, however, Recently I am unable to see/add layout items in Graphical Layout option.

I have some items in layout which does not support android wear (api level 20). I already have set the target api level to 19 (from 8) while setting up project. Its same now when i confirmed from menifest file.

The problem is in graphical layout that green android dropdown does not allow me to select api level lower than 20. Its just not there. Even choosing select best automatically also does not work. It won't just allow me to unselect level 20 for layout. Please also check the screen shot below

[image]

BtW that unsupported element is EditText (unsupported for level 20).

Here goes MY XML of this layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.khu84.myfirstapplication.TextActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommand"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/text_et"
    android:password="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_bResults" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text_tvResults" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I select api level less than 20 for layout? any help is appreciated. level is already 8 to 19 for project. Target 19.

Comment: AFAIK, you need the SDK Platform components for the other API levels installed in the SDK Manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am new to android, so any further help on how can I do that will be appreciated. A bit more details will also help.

Comment: The SDK Manager is in Tools > Android in the Android Studio main menu. SDK Platform entries will appear in the SDK Manager. You can also find out more about adding packages via the SDK Manager in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)